# liquid slider - work with ajax

Tags: html, ajax, json, slider

I'm using the Liquid Slider for my site.

I have a lot of pages of projects and i want to use this slider with ajax to load any single html content in each slides but I don't know where to start with it...i have found this link but it  doesn't work

http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/tutorials/dynamically-add-content-to-a-panel-when-clicked-using-ajax/

thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try starting here on the examples page:

http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/examples/page2.html#ajax

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Yes, I read this page but my problem is with "api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());"...it doesn't work..i load an html page in a div but height doesn't change..

Answer (score 1):

ps. this is my script:

```
var api2 = $.data( $('#slider-7')[0], 'liquidSlider');

$.ajax({
    complete: function() {

      $('#loader').html('This JSON request was faked, and you will surely want to write a real one in it\'s place' + $('.profile').html()).load('example.html');

      api2.adjustHeight(true, api2.getHeight());

   }    

});
```